# Получить дельту значений в столбце DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Имеется один столбец, необходимо добавить в DF второй по определенной формуле . В данном случае столбец Б - это изменение (дельта) значений в столбце А

Например, есть исходный столбец А

```
А
1
2
6
8
12
```

На выходе должны получить столбец

Б

```
-
1
4
2
4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь методом [Series.diff()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.diff.html):

```
In [89]: df
Out[89]:
    А
0   1
1   2
2   6
3   8
4  12

In [90]: df['delta'] = df['А'].diff()

In [91]: df
Out[91]:
    А  delta
0   1    nan
1   2  1.000
2   6  4.000
3   8  2.000
4  12  4.000
```

NOTE: если в столбце (`pandas.Series`) присутствует хотя бы одно вещественное (`float`) значение или значение `NaN` (Not a Number), то тип столбца будет восприниматься как `float*` (`float16`, `float32`, `float64`). Таким образом преобразовать столбец к целому типу не получиться пока присутствует хотя бы одно значение `NaN`.

*Workaround:*

```
In [142]: df['delta'] = df['А'].diff().fillna(0).astype('int16')

In [143]: df
Out[143]:
    А  delta
0   1      0
1   2      1
2   6      4
3   8      2
4  12      4

In [144]: df.dtypes
Out[144]:
А        int64
delta    int16
dtype: object
```